# Econometric model for finding optimal number of workers per sq. meter

Tags: regression, econometrics

I am probably just a beginner in Econometrics compared to most of the people here. I know basic Econometrics (undergrad level), but always looking to improve my knowledge.

However, I have a dataset that looks similar to this (I can probably get a hold of additional variables if needed):

[image]

I am interested in creating an econometric model that analyzes the store size/worker relationship. In other words, based on the store´s sales amount, I am interested in finding the optimal number of workers per square meter.
I assume I have to contemplate decreasing marginal returns on the number of workers.

My model is probably missing some other explanatory variables, which I can probably get a hold of.

My -- beginner -- approach would be to create an interaction term between the store size and the number of workers while contemplating decreasing marginal returns (if that makes any sense). However, I have no idea on how to approach this problem.

Any information on references/tips/books on how to approach this problem would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution might be easier than you think. Why not try something like the following (denote as $x$ the ratio of number of workers to square footage)

$
log(sales) = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1x + \alpha_2x^{2}
$

The reason I'm suggesting a second degree fit is because its concievable that as $x$ rises (i.e. you have more workers) at some point your sales must turn around and start decreasing. Finding the peak on this curve could get you the optimal $x$ value and thus the optimal value of number of employees per sq foot.

There is a good collection of books listed [here](http://bayesianthink.blogspot.com/2012/12/the-best-books-to-learn-probability.html) if you want to learn more. Hope that helps